# List GCP Bucket objects in firebase using nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get the list of objects from GCP bucket to my app deployed in firebase. The code for it is as follows:

> apis.js

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'gs://cloud-dev-setup';

exports.getBucketData = (req, res) => {
    storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles().then(files => {
        [files] = files;
        let data = [];
        files.forEach(file => {
            data.push(file.name);
        });
        res.send(data);
    }).catch( error => {
        res.send('catch');
    });
}
```

> index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const apis = require('./apis');
const app = express();
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

app.get('/fileList', apis.getBucketData);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

> firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

When it is run locally, it gets me the object list and works as expected.

But upon deploying to the firebase server, I get the following error:

> TypeError: stream.destroy is not a function
>       at onResultSet (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/index.js:245:24)
>       at request (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:1344:17)
>       at Util.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:141:9)
>       at retryRequest (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:422:22)
>       at onResponse (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:222:13
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
>
> Function execution took 841 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
>
> Error: function crashed out of request scope Function cannot be
>   executed.

I have been referencing this [GCP page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-nodejs) for setting the app.